# TensorFlowJS: how to have an output shape with less dimensions than the input shape?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Consider the following code:

```
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 50, inputShape: [2,41,2,8]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 50}));
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd',  loss: 'meanSquaredError', metrics:['mae']});

model.summary()

const X = tf.tensor(Xs)
const y = tf.tensor(Ys);

model.fit(X,y,{epochs: 100}).then((h) => {

});
```

This model gives the following summary:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                Input Shape               Output shape              Param #   
==========================================================================================
dense_Dense1 (Dense)        [[null,2,41,2,8]]         [null,2,41,2,50]          450       
__________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense2 (Dense)        [[null,2,41,2,50]]        [null,2,41,2,50]          2550      
==========================================================================================
Total params: 3000
Trainable params: 3000
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________
```

When I run the script I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense2 to have 5 dimension(s). but got array with shape 6,1,41,1
```

Does someone know how I can solve this?

I've tried flattening the layer, changed dimensions of the tensor (not preferred), specifying the tensor dimensions, but I am stuck with getting the right output layer.